# Find bluetooth devices with same app installed

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I want to be able to find a list of bluetooth devices, but only those with my app installed on it. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: You are essentially asking how to turn a device into a bluetooth beacon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is somewhat unclear. The answer will depend on what kind of architecture you have in mind.

Bluetooth discovery only returns "hardware information" (device ID, MAC address, GATT, etc.), and *if a device install my app* is "software information". There must be an extra layer of architecture to bridge this.

**If you are just making a self-contained app:** it's impossible. There is just no way to magically send this information over Bluetooth broadcast radio.

**If you plan to have a back-end server for your app:** it will be a very bad practice for obvious reasons, but potentially you could register the Bluetooth MAC address of the device that installed you app to your back-end server. When Bluetooth discovery finished, check with your server and filter the ones with MAC addresses registered.